# onLocationChanged not working if time intervel not set in LocationRequest

Tags: android, location, android-googleapiclient

when i set time intervel in LocationRequest then location getting perfectly
using this code

```
private static final long INTERVAL = 500 * 1;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 500 * 1;
private static final int SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT = 5;

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

but when i remove these line then onLocationChanged not working. is it neccessary to set time intervel in LocationRequest?

```
 mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
 mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
```

i want to get location according to displacement not according to time intervel.

Comment: as far as I can rememeber, if you don´t set the interval, it doesn´t update with interval (or after long time, something like 60 minutes), only if location is changed.

Comment: if you not set interval you will never get location. i am continuously driving but my location only update after time interval.  onLocationChanged depends on time intervel not on displacement.

Answer (score 0):

It also surprised me, please someone correct me if i'm interpreting wrongly.

From the [LocationRequest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/LocationRequest.java#145) source code;

```
private long mInterval = 60 * 60 * 1000;   // 60 minutes
private long mFastestInterval = (long)(mInterval / FASTEST_INTERVAL_FACTOR);  // 10 minutes
```

If you dont set `setInterval`and `setFastestInterval`, then they keep their default values.

So, when you set only `mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(...);`

Then fused provider considers values like

Interval : 60 minutes, Fastest Interval : 10 minutes, SmallestDisplacement : 5m

As a result, it seeming like "not working"

Comment: yes its not working. you will get new location after 10 min. Why we depends on time interval. why new location not getting after 5m displacement

Comment: I mean't it's actually working. Due to interval values have default, you didn't see a possible `onLocationChanged` call (maybe you didn't wait at least 10 minutes or more)